# Why are there discrepancies between my if statements?

Tags: objective-c

I come from a Swift background. I am trying to implement a singly linked list in Objective C for practice...

This is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LinkedList.h"

@implementation LikedList
Node *head;
- (void)insert:(NSString *)value{
    if (head == nil){
        NSLog(@"*** Inserted value at head!");
        Node *node = [[Node alloc] init: value];
        head = node;
    } else {
        Node *currentNode;
        currentNode = head;

        while (currentNode.next != nil) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }

        Node *newNode = [[Node alloc] init: value];
        currentNode.next = newNode;
    }

    [self printLinkedListElements];
}

-(void) printLinkedListElements{
    Node *currentNode = head;
    int iterator  = 0;
    while (currentNode != nil){
        iterator = iterator + 1;
        NSLog(@"The iteration number is: %d", iterator);
        NSLog(@"%@\n", currentNode.value);
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    NSLog(@"***********************************");
}

@end
```

In my `insert` method I first check if the head is empty. I get two different results when I type `self.head == nil`, `head == nil`

**When I type `self.head == nil` I get the following log:**

*** Inserted value at head!

The iteration number is: 1

ValueOne

---

*** Inserted value at head!

The iteration number is: 1

ValueTwo

---

*** Inserted value at head!

The iteration number is: 1

ValueThree

---

*** Inserted value at head!

The iteration number is: 1

ValueFour

---

*** Inserted value at head!

The iteration number is: 1

ValueFive

---

**However, when I type `head == nil` I get the result I am looking for:**

*** Inserted value at head!

The iteration number is: 1

ValueOne

---

*** The iteration number is: 1

ValueOne

*** The iteration number is: 2

ValueTwo

---

*** The iteration number is: 1

ValueOne

*** The iteration number is: 2

ValueTwo

*** The iteration number is: 3

ValueThree

---

*** The iteration number is: 1

ValueOne

*** The iteration number is: 2

ValueTwo

*** The iteration number is: 3

ValueThree

*** The iteration number is: 4

ValueFour

---

*** The iteration number is: 1

ValueOne

*** The iteration number is: 2

ValueTwo

*** The iteration number is: 3

ValueThree

*** The iteration number is: 4

ValueFour

*** The iteration number is: 5

ValueFive

---

Can you please help me understand why I am getting the two different outputs when using `self.head == nil` as opposed to `head == nil`?

Comment: `@implementation MyClass Node *head;` That's not how you declare a property for a class. `self.head` shouldn't work. It means that you declared it somewhere else, and then `self.head` (class property) is not the same as `head` (not a class property), pointers differs.

Comment: I was under the impression that `self` refers to the current instance of the class; therefore, `self.head` is referring to an instance property not a class property... Isn't that the case in Objective C? @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have declared a global variable named `head`:

```
@implementation LikedList
Node *head;  // <-- THIS IS A GLOBAL VARIABLE
```

When you say `head == nil`, you're referring to the global variable. When you say `self.head`, you're referring to an instance property (which you didn't show the declaration of). You never assign to the instance property, so looking at its value always returns nil.

Presumably, you want to support multiple instances of `LikedList`, so you should get rid of the global variable, and use `self.head` everywhere, like this:

```
@implementation LikedList

- (void)insert:(NSString *)value{
    if (self.head == nil){
        NSLog(@"*** Inserted value at head!");
        Node *node = [[Node alloc] init: value];
        self.head = node;
    } else {
        Node *currentNode;
        currentNode = self.head;

        while (currentNode.next != nil) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }

        Node *newNode = [[Node alloc] init: value];
        currentNode.next = newNode;
    }

    [self printLinkedListElements];
}

-(void) printLinkedListElements{
    Node *currentNode = self.head;
    int iterator  = 0;
    while (currentNode != nil){
        iterator = iterator + 1;
        NSLog(@"The iteration number is: %d", iterator);
        NSLog(@"%@\n", currentNode.value);
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    NSLog(@"***********************************");
}

@end
```

Comment: The global variable, `Node *head` is this the equivalent of declaring a static class variable in Swift `static var head: Node?`

Comment: It is similar to that. They are both global variables but in Swift, the variable is named `LikedList.head` and in Objective-C the variable is just named `head`.